# Search for a semicolon in PHP POST

Tags: php, html

I would like to know if it is possible to search through a `$_POST` variable and if a `";"` is found then trigger an if statement.

For example:

```
if ";" is True{
 XXXXXX
}
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what your `$_POST` array would look like and your expected results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check if the character is found in your string.

```
<?php

if(strpos($_POST['yourkey'],';')!==false){
    //if it gets here, a ; was found
    }
```

You have to use a strict check (=== or !==) for the position returned. Otherwise, if strpos returns a 0 because the ; is the first character in the string, it will resolve to boolean `false`, meaning the result is misinterpreted.

Comment: This looks like this is exactly what i want let me test it before I accept. Thanks So Much

Answer (score 1):

You can tell if a char exists in a string using [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

It returns the position of the string.

```
strpos($haystack, $needle);
```

Be careful of you result being the first position, i.e. 0. As 0 equates to false in PHP.

In this case use === to test for 0 rather than false.